# Fuzzy compare and aggregate similar records within a single single column data-frame

Tags: r, aggregate, fuzzy-comparison

The current requirement is to aggregate a single column and supply a count with the per row.  There are a couple of issues that I am encountering that I need assistance with:

1. Many lines are similar but not exact due to a parameter or other information like an error code.
2. The data being worked with is unpredictable so the aggregate needs to have a certain level of flexibility to match.
3. There is no way of knowing where the variance will occur or the pattern of the string.
4. There is no way of knowing in advance either the messages or the values that make some of the rows distinct.

---

So I am looking to make the following:

```
TextData
Message : @p_id is not valid
Message : @p_id is not valid
Message : @p_id is not valid
Message : @p_id is not valid
Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=11933
Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=21944
Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=31933
Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=41931
Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=51993
The duplicate key value is (129).
The duplicate key value is (129).
The duplicate key value is (135).
```

Matched and counted into something like this:

```
Count    TextData                                    Values
4        Message : @p_id is not valid               
5        Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=  11933,21944,31933,41931,51993
3        The duplicate key value is ().              129,135
```

If that is not possible, then at least into this

```
Count    TextData
4        Message : @p_id is not valid
5        Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=
3        The duplicate key value is ().
```

---

I've searched for hours trying to find a solution for something like this but have not found an example that worked or fit my situation.

Comment: Is their only on parameter per line or could their be more than one?  If their are more than one, do you know what they all are? Because on option would be to use regular expressions to extract the parameter values into a new column, which would greatly simplify your problem.

Comment: Hi @IanWesley, I haven't seen any cases where their is more than 1 per line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data.table solution

```
library( data.table )
library( stringr )
#read data
dt <- fread(
  "Message : @p_id is not valid
   Message : @p_id is not valid
  Message : @p_id is not valid
  Message : @p_id is not valid
  Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=11933
  Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=21944
  Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=31933
  Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=41931
  Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=51993
  The duplicate key value is (129).
  The duplicate key value is (129).
  The duplicate key value is (135).", header = FALSE, sep = "")

#see if a string with numbers is present in the text, if so: extract
dt[, `:=`( id = stringr::str_extract( V1, "\\d+" ),
           V1 = ifelse( grepl ( "\\d+", V1 ), gsub( "\\d+", "", V1 ), V1 ) ) ]

#summarise    
dt[, list( Count = .N, values = toString( unique( id ) ) ), by = V1][]

#                                            V1 Count                            values
# 1:               Message : @p_id is not valid     4                                NA
# 2: Message : ID record does not exist: @p_Id=     5 11933, 21944, 31933, 41931, 51993
# 3:             The duplicate key value is ().     3                          129, 135
```

Comment: Hi @Wimpel, there are potentially an unlimited variation of messages so I added some additional example data to reflect that.  There is really no way to hard code the patterns.

Comment: @artofsql see updated answer... used `gsub` to 'wipe' the numeric part (when present)...